# Using master templates with weld

Tags: node.js

With jade and express, I can use layout.jade as a master template. Is it possible to do the same with weld?

The weld documentation is at https://github.com/hij1nx/weld but I didn't see anything about master templates.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that weld doesn't support 'out of the box' master templates and 'sub' templates.